# BBOX select accuracy

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers 3 application. When using a box to select features from GeoServer WFS layer (request=GetFeature) I get inaccurate results see image below. The layer is served from a PostGIS DB. However I have the same data in a shapefile served via the same GeoServer and when I change to that layer I get only one feature selected in the same example like the picture below.

Any help here would be good as I am not sure where the problem is it seems to me that the problem is in PostGIS but not sure. Any idea even how to troubleshoot this further would help.

BTW. This happens randomly in many locations this is not the only problem spot. And it seems to happen more on as I zoom in closer.

[image]

The query passed to PostGIS looks like this:

```
WHERE  "the_geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (
```

Picture below shows that the query is not doing an intersection (which is what I expect) but rather an intersect with features' extents. The green BBOX selected those three yellow lines above it.

How do I change/fix this?

How do I get GeoServer to use ST_Intersects function?

[image]

Comment: what is the projection used? Is it the same in the wfs request and the postgis table

Comment: 3857 and it is the same across the board

Comment: I just noticed that almost anywhere I click the feature on the right gets selected. So even thought  this happens in different places it seems to always pick up the same extra feature(s).

Comment: try to rebuild your spatial index. maybe import the "working" shapefile into Postgis and try with that........ good luck

Comment: Bbox is making a fast && query from spatial index as you have seen and features get selected if their bounding boxes intersect with the bbox in query. For accurate and slower results use Intersects filter instead. Use cql_filter or OGC style XML filter for that.

Comment: This did it I replaced bbox with INTERSECT and it all worked &cql_filter=INTERSECTS(the_geom, POLYGON((...))) I guess I was using the bbox a wrong way. Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: Bbox behavior is intentional. Query from index is faster and you get always everything you want and sometimes a bit more. Speed is usually more important than exactly correct result set for example when rendering a map.

Answer (score 1):

They seem to be parts of a **MULTILINESTRING**.

Check the types of geometry in your geom columns  by :

```
SELECT distinct ST_GeometryType(geom) from roads
```

And amend where necessary - assuming that was the problem.

EDIT:

To eliminate thats a db end error try and select the features using the same BBOX straight from the database:

> select count(geom) from table lateral where geom &&
>   ST_MakeEnvelope(lrx, lry, urx,ury, 3857);

If you get the indented number of results you can deduct then that the error is not in the database.

Comment: my column in PostGIS is Linestring the_geom geometry(LineString,3857),

Comment: this is the query being executed by Geoserver WHERE  "the_geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ( ... Is it possible this query is going against feature extents rather then looking for features that intersect? See how that line is angled and the bbox would be within its bounds.

Comment: BTW tried the ST_MakeEnvelope suggestions and get the same result

Comment: if you can id the query from the logs that is actually being executed; by all means use that to debug.

Comment: It would be safe to say that gs, postgis works correctly.  '&&' filters against bbox of features; so **double check** that the polygon inside st_geomfromtext is your intended bbox. Also you could use bbox geom to check where it intersects with that rogue geometry.

Comment: I am suggesting as well to check the proposed link in your question if there is any racing/misuse conditions especially in the logic where you get your bbox coords before querying gs.

Comment: In PostGIS I replaced the query with ST_Intersects and it gave the right answer. So is there a way to get geoserver to use ST_Intersects?